# Use multiple googleservices-info.plist in the same app simultaneously

Tags: ios, flutter, google-signin

I have 1 Firebase project and 1 GCP project.

I use the Firebase project for analytics and the GCP for social login.

It works nicely for web apps. But now, I'm trying to integrate the social login in a Flutter app for Android and iOS that is already using the Firebase project.

The Firebase project uses the `googleservices-info.plist` as well the GCP project.

The problem is. How can I use these multiple projects together, as they colide with the `.plist` files?

Comment: I'm on the same situation. I already have the Google login in GCP and now I'm adding push notifications in Firebase. Did you find a solution? I'm thinking of moving everything to Firebase and get rid of GCP.